# Pass headers as parameter to a javascript post request (react-native)

Tags: javascript, json, react-native, http-headers, javascript-objects

I'm passing the body parameters this way:
`body: JSON.stringify(parameters),`
where `parameters` is structured like `parameters.name = 'name'`, ...
I would like to accomplish the same with the headers but the key (of the key/value) contains `-`.

```
headers: {
    'X-Public-App-Authentication': 'Token ' + token,
    'content-type': 'application/json'
},
```

how can I pass this header as a parameter so I can just write `headers: JSON.stringify(heads),` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following are the same `parameters.name` and `parameters['name']`

So you could do the following

`headers['X-Public-App-Authentication'] = 'Token ' + token`